# Saving cdrs manually using avp_db_query in Opensips

Tags: voip, telecommunication, opensips

Is there a way to record cdrs manually using avp_db_query in opensips. I am using ACC table to record cdrs and than running procedure to transfer data to another table. But this put a lot of overhead on my DB due to too many calls. So is there any way that I can put directly cdrs in my actual table using AVP_DB_QUERY, I am doing for missing and not accepted calls but don't know how to do it for Answered calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can program OpenSIPS to push CDR events over to the [event interface](http://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Tutorials-EventInterface) instead of writing them to the database with:

```
do_accounting("evi", "cdr|failed");
```

Next, using the [event_route](http://www.opensips.org/html/docs/modules/3.0.x/event_route) module, you may subscribe to the [E_ACC_CDR](http://www.opensips.org/html/docs/modules/3.0.x/acc.html#event_E_ACC_CDR) event by defining the route below, where you can perform your [avp_db_query](http://www.opensips.org/html/docs/modules/3.0.x/avpops.html#func_avp_db_query):

```
event_route [E_ACC_CDR]
{
    fetch_event_params(...);
    avp_db_query(...);
}
```